# Can the state of the Counter in the example Blazor project be preserved between page switches?

Tags: c#, blazor

In the default example project for both server-side Blazor and WebAssembly Blazor projects, the Counter example resets to 0 every time you move between the pages. However, on the ASP.NET React example project, the Counter does not reset between page switches.

Is there a way for a component like the Counter to preserve state between page navigation in Blazor (at least for the WebAssembly project that isn't making any server calls)?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this exact scenario is discussed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.0#client-side-in-the-browser

Seems Blazor just doesn't handle it out-of-the-box, but you just need to use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Using the `Blazor.Extensions.Storage` NuGet package (https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage):

```
@page "/counter"

@inject ISessionStorage SessionStorage
@using Blazor.Extensions.Storage.Interfaces

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        currentCount = await SessionStorage.GetItem<int>("counter");
    }

    private async void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        await SessionStorage.SetItem<int>("counter", currentCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cover this in my article (works for server side Blazor as well as client side (WebAssembly) Blazor): [Implementing State Management In Blazor](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/28)

Add a class called CounterState.cs using the following code:

```
    public class CounterState
    {
        public int CurrentCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Register this class, using Dependency Injection, in the the Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<CounterState>();
```

Add the following code to the top of the .razor code page:

```
@inject CounterState CounterState
```

Change the following code:

```
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
```

To:

```
<p>Current count: @CounterState.CurrentCount</p>
```

Finally, change the code section to the following:

```
@code {
    void IncrementCount()
    {
        // ** SESSION STATE
        int CurrentCount = CounterState.CurrentCount;
        CurrentCount++;
        // Set Current count on the Session State object
        CounterState.CurrentCount = CurrentCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do note that Scoped is _almost_ like a Session but this counterState won't survive SignalR reconnects. Good enough for some scenarios but localState is a safer solution.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - In most cases you want to track 'session state' and you would want all values not tied to the current session (for example the most recently selected 'Category') to 'go away' if the session was unloaded otherwise the user logs in again and you try to load a 'Category' that is no longer valid. Also, if you have 'sensitive' information such as 'account id' you do not want to store them in the user's local web browser. You want to store it securely in-memory and yo want it to completely disappear from everywhere :)

Comment: Yes, but I think localStore is slightly more 'session' than the SignalR context.

Comment: Please see my implementation of a generic service  and let me know what you think of it as a general solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044349/blazor-generic-service-implementation-to-store-page-state-counter-page-example

Comment: @MichaelWashington  Feel free to rip this off and add it as an example on your site.  https://github.com/rdavi10471a2/BlazorApp1

Comment: @MichaelWashington Your link is broken

Answer (score 1):

For server side Blazor if you want the counter value to be persisted/updated on all tabs/clients you could simply store it in a static variable and rerender if the value changes.

[image]

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Static Counter</h1>

<p>Current static count: <span style="font-size:42px">@currentCount</span></p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    public static int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;

        StaticCount.FireUpdate();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        StaticCount.NewCounterValue += OnNewCounterValue;
    }

    void OnNewCounterValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        StaticCount.NewCounterValue -= OnNewCounterValue;
    }

}

@code{
    public static class StaticCount
    {
        public static event EventHandler NewCounterValue;

        public static void FireUpdate()
        {
            NewCounterValue?.Invoke(null, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

You could also do this with a (singleton) service and even persist the value in a database if you want to keep the value between server restarts.

Comment: Can you provide some details describing the approach you're using?  The OP asked about both server-side and web assembly (client-side), not just server-side.  I also got the impression the OP was simply asking about moving between the template apps (e.g., weather and counter) and preserving the counter as opposed to preserving between multiple tabs.

Comment: For server side Blazor..

"StateHasChanged", "ASP.NET Core Blazor lifecycle"

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer about Blazor state management that looks into this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65609519/3850405

My recommendation would be an in-memory state container service.

Example:

StateContainer.cs

```
public class StateContainer
{
    public string Property { get; set; } = "Initial value from StateContainer";

    public event Action OnChange;

    public void SetProperty(string value)
    {
        Property = value;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }

    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

Program.Main (Blazor WebAssembly):

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<StateContainer>();
```

Startup.ConfigureServices (Blazor Server):

```
services.AddSingleton<StateContainer>();
```

Pages/Component1.razor

```
@page "/Component1"
@inject StateContainer StateContainer
@implements IDisposable

<h1>Component 1</h1>

<p>Component 1 Property: <b>@StateContainer.Property</b></p>

<p>
    <button @onclick="ChangePropertyValue">Change Property from Component 1</button>
</p>

<Component2 />

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    private void ChangePropertyValue()
    {
        StateContainer.SetProperty($"New value set in Component 1 {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

Shared/Component2.razor

```
@inject StateContainer StateContainer
@implements IDisposable

<h2>Component 2</h2>

<p>Component 2 Property: <b>@StateContainer.Property</b></p>

<p>
    <button @onclick="ChangePropertyValue">Change Property from Component 2</button>
</p>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    private void ChangePropertyValue()
    {
        StateContainer.SetProperty($"New value set in Component 2 {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#in-memory-state-container-service-wasm