# How can I preserve data when switching between tabs in Blazor component?

Tags: blazor, razor-pages, blazor-client-side, matblazor

I am using MatTabGroup control in a Razor page. I have a table in the first tab which displays a list of field names in one column and an input box in the second column to capture value for each field.

How can I create dynamic properties to bind to the  controls so it can preserve the data when switching between tabs? The field names are not standard and the number of field names are also not known at compile time. They need to be generated dynamically.

Thanks for any suggestions!

```
<MatTabGroup>
    <MatTab Label="Tab1">
        <ItemsTable Items="@lstFieldNames">
            <TableHeader>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </TableHeader>
            <RowTemplate Context="fieldname">
                <td>@fieldname</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="@fieldname" type="text" class="input-md"/>
                </td>
            </RowTemplate>
        </ItemsTable>
    </MatTab>

   <MatTab Label="Tab2">
   </MatTab>
</MatTabGroup>


@code {

   BlazorApp.Shared.Models.Template tmp;

    List<string> lstFieldNames = new List<string>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (tmp != null)
        {
            //Example FieldTemplate: //{CustName}/{Address}/{City}/{State}/{Zip}
            var fieldnames = Regex.Matches(tmp.FieldTemplate, @"{\w+}");

            foreach (var fieldname in fieldnames)
            {
                lstFieldNames.Add(fieldname.ToString().TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the state of the Counter in the example Blazor project be preserved between page switches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126869/can-the-state-of-the-counter-in-the-example-blazor-project-be-preserved-between)

Comment: Blazor state management. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126869/can-the-state-of-the-counter-in-the-example-blazor-project-be-preserved-between

Comment: Why does Blazor insist on destroying non-visible part of the UI instead of just hiding them?