# Are there any Pitfalls to this approach which I am not seeing

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, blazor

Service Registration

```
  services.AddScoped(typeof(PageStorageService<>), typeof(PageStorageService<>));
```

Service Declaration

```
 public interface IStoredPage<T>
    {   
        T PageState { get; set; }
    }
    public class PageStorageService<T> : IStoredPage<T>
    {
        public T PageState { get; set; }
    }
```

Usage in CounterPage

```
@page "/counter"

@using BlazorApp1.Data
 
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

@inject PageStorageService<Counter> StorageService

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {

    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // reset what we want from stored copy
        if (StorageService.PageState != null)
        {
            currentCount = StorageService.PageState.currentCount;

        }
        //reconnect for this page lifespan we have a reference copy of the pages class
        // which is copied into the service  Or so experimentation seems to indicate
        StorageService.PageState = this;
    }
```

I have run multiple small tests like the one above)

And this Improvement to use OnInitialziedAsync ( an additional list was added to the counter class that is not shown )

```
@using BlazorApp1.Data
 
<h1>Counter2</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<p>PageStateNull : @PageStateNullCount</p>

<div>  @((MarkupString)string.Join("\r\n", TestDataSave))  </div>

    @inject PageStorageService<Counter2> StorageService

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

    @code {

        private int PageStateNullCount = 0;

        private List<string> TestDataSave;

        private int currentCount = 0;

        private void IncrementCount()
        {
            TestDataSave.Add("<div>count before Inc : " + currentCount.ToString() + "</div>");
            currentCount++;
            TestDataSave.Add("<div>count after Inc :" + currentCount.ToString() + "<div>");

        }

        protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            // reset what we want from stored copy
            if (StorageService.PageState != null)
            {
                currentCount = StorageService.PageState.currentCount;
                TestDataSave = StorageService.PageState.TestDataSave;
                PageStateNullCount = StorageService.PageState.PageStateNullCount;
            }
            else
            {
                PageStateNullCount++;
                //create for the first time aka read from database
                TestDataSave = new List<string>();
                TestDataSave.Add("<div>OnParametersSetAsync</div>");
            }


            //reconnect 
            StorageService.PageState = this;

            return base.OnInitializedAsync();
        }
```

This seems pretty clean and straight forward to me. But more eyes are generally better. It follows the same general pattern as the Local storage solutions i have seen (in my case I am only looking to store filters and tab selections for a dashboard type app -- I won't have large forms etc and I am more interested in the advantages of having page state in memory than the occasional server crash . The fact that it is injected as a service means any page that I want to use can opt In.. etc
Thoughts, rocks, things I should have thought of?

Comment: Similar to approach here and many other places but none of those made it generic so it would work for any page or used the direct simple reference to the page using this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126869/can-the-state-of-the-counter-in-the-example-blazor-project-be-preserved-between